# VSTO - Getting all accounts

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In my addin I need to get all accounts. Now I using

```
Application.Session.Accounts
```

but it not contains accounts that added after application start. How to get all accounts (even if it will be added in current aplication session) without restarting application?

Comment: What kind of account are you adding? How is it added?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - I add it via "File->Add Account" dialog - mostly it gmail account

Comment: Do you see the same problem in OutlookSpy if you click Namespace button, select Accounts, click Browse, select Count property? Is the new account visible if you click IOlkAccountManager button?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - in OutlookSpy same problem, after adding new account count value still set to 3 [image](https://i.imgur.com/c6Yn2xo.jpg)

Comment: Both Namespace.Accounts.Count and IOlkAccountManager?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - Namespace.Accounts.Count is not updating, but IMAPISession and IOlkAccountManager provide me actual information. Can you provide me how to use one of them?

Answer (score 1):

If `Namespace.Accounts.Count` does not get updated, you can try to use [IOlkAccountManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960327.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Extended MAPI interface (if you are using C++ or Delphi). You can play with that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IOlkAccountManager button.
In case of languages other than C++ or Delphi, I can only suggest [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Accounts` collection (returns [RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) object). It does not cache stale data (it is refreshed every time you retrieve the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Accounts` property) and exposes a few [events](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm#events) that fire when accounts are added/modified/deleted.